# Issue with Tabulator table resizing and "layout:'fitColumns'" option

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

I am having issues with the "layout:'fitColumns'" option when setting up a table with "Tabulator". The resizing is not working as expected: either it enlarges the page body itself (approach 1), or it automatically resizes back to its original size (approach 2).

I have tried two approaches, but neither of them is working correctly.

In the first attempt, I simply inserted the table like this:

```html
<div class="container-fluid flex-1">
  <div class="card h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div id="roles"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, resizing the table does not add a scroll bar to the table itself, but instead enlarges the entire ".card" element, and the scroll bar is visible on the document body itself.

--
In the second attempt, I tried the following approach:

```html
<div class="container-fluid flex-1">
  <div class="card h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="tree" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 150px;">
        <div id="roles" style="position: absolute; width: 100%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, I am able to resize the table correctly, but as soon as I release the click, the table automatically redraws itself and returns to its original size.

--
Here is the code for my Tabulator table:

```js
new Tabulator("#roles", {
  layout:"fitColumns",
  columns: [
    {
      title: "Nom du rôle",
      field: "roles_name",
      widthGrow: 4,
      formatter: function (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
        const roles_admin = cell.getRow().getData()["roles_admin"];
        if (!roles_admin) {
          return cell.getValue();
        } else {
          return "<div class='d-flex align-items-center'><i class='material-icons fs-6'>star</i>" + cell.getValue() + "</div>";
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title: "Nombres d'utilisateurs",
      field: "count_users",
      sorter: "number",
      headerHozAlign: "right",
      hozAlign: "right"
    },
    {
      title: "Date de création",
      field: "roles_createdAt"
    },
    {
      title: "Actions",
      field: "actions",
      headerHozAlign: "right",
      hozAlign: "right",
      formatter: function (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
        const roles_admin = cell.getRow().getData()["roles_admin"];

        if (!roles_admin) {
          return "<div class='dir-rtl'>" +
            "<div class='position-absolute'>" +
            "<button class='btn-link'><i class='material-icons fs-4'>delete</i></button>" +
            "<button class='btn-link'><i class='material-icons fs-4'>edit</i></button>" +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>";
        } else {
          return "";
        }
      }
    },
  ],

  rowFormatter: function (row) {
    // Récupérer la valeur de la cellule à formater en gras
    const roles_admin = row.getData()["roles_admin"];

    // Si la valeur est "valeur_à_mettre_en_gras", ajouter la classe CSS pour le gras
    if (roles_admin) {
      row.getElement().classList.add("fw-bold");
      row.freeze();
    }
  },

  data: "/administration/roles/getRoles"
});
```